# What is angular2-mdl, where can i find it, what did it provide?

Tags: javascript, angular, material-design, angular2-mdl, angular-mdl

- What is angular2-mdl?
- Why does angular2-mdl exist?
- Where can I find the sources?
- Where can I find a demo?
- Is it installable by npm?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**angular2-mdl** are angular 2 components, directives and styles based on material design lite (http://getmdl.io). It is available as npm package `npm install angular2-mdl`. The sources are available on github (https://github.com/mseemann/angular2-mdl) All components are documented here: http://mseemann.io/angular2-mdl.

It exists because:

- It allows you to write short html templates to get a material design lite look and feel.
- It integrates the components with the latest version of angular2 (2.0 Final).
- It make two way binding and reactive forms available.
- It is themeable by switching the styles from mdl or by using the original scss.i
- It uses the well tested and widely used original css from getmdl.
- It is dynamic. You can create and destroy components during the lifetime of your app and the ui is going to change as expected. There is no need to hack around with the mdl javascript.